# How to specify file storage

Tags: c++

I work with C ++ and I am almost new.
My question is how to specify where to save the text file.
For example, I wrote a program that creates a text file called "usertext.txt"
And it automatically creates the text file in the code storage. But I want to create a folder For example called patch and save the text file there .
How can this be done?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using std::ios;
using std::fstream ;
int main(){
  fstream filetext;
  filetext.open("usertext.txt", ios::app) ;
  filetext << "hellow world!" ;
  filetext.close();
}
```

Comment: So what folder is folder `patch` in?

Comment: Where the program is inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the functions in the [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) to create the directory first.  Then use the directory as part of the full name when opening the file.

```
std::filesystem::create_directories ("/path/to/");
filetext.open("/path/to/usertext.txt", ios::app) ;
```

You can also use the `path` class to form the full name if the user gives the file name separately from the directory.

The function [`create_directories`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory) will create each part of the path that does not already exist; if the full thing already exists it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the path to the folder

```
filetext.open("patch/usertext.txt", ios::app);
```

Note however that it won't handle the directory creation if it doesn't exist.

If you can use C++17, you can probably manage the path better using [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path). But it might be overkill for your use case.